# show.blade.php file doesnt have property in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have problem with redirection to a created website which has functions to edit, show and delete just created user in form(this form works properly)

What do i need to do to make things run well like in creating user form?

Not sure what I can try because I'm a starter who just grabbed tutorial from this website:
http://demonuts.com/laravel-5-8-crud/

I had an issue with installing it on Termux(quite less though than on Raspberry) and this experience placed on Windows OS where all went surprisingly more smooth except that last part on show.blade.php file.

Show.blade.php file(which has a screenshot on the website)

```
<a href="/players/{{ $player->id }}/edit"> Edit Player </a>
```

After creating this file I should see the form with edit, delete user buttons.
None of them appear

Kindly pls for a help

Peter

Comment: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\xampp\firstapp\resources\views\players\show.blade.php)

Comment: Try either change that particular route to /edit/{{player}}, or pushing that route rule to first place (before the other /player routes).

Comment: Your question is very unclear, based on this error this has nothing to do with the install but show us the rest of the code so we can reproduce it, like controller logic